# ODBC connection in a Blazor web app running .net 8 framework

Tags: sql, c, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I've very new to web development and never used the new Blazor implementation.  I'm trying to set up a web app to connect to a 2000 Microsoft SQL Server.  I can't use the standard System.Data.SqlClient as this doesn't support SQL 2000.  I believe that I have to use the ODBC connection.  Problem is that I cant find any examples out there that have done this.  I know it's a lot to ask but would anyone have an example app of this or know where I might find a solution.

The SQL server isn't local and it uses SQL authentication. I'm using Visual Studio 2022, .net 8

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following:
Search and Open ODBC Data Source Administrator and confirm the "driver name."
[image]
Then you could try with a console app and install package `System.Data.Odbc`

```
OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
};
builder.Add("SERVER", "192.168.2.68");
builder.Add("Port", "1433");
builder.Add("DATABASE", "test11");
builder.Add("UID", "sa");
builder.Add("PWD", "xxxxxx");
//builder.Add("TrustServerCertificate", "True");

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Teams";
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    connection.Open();
    OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    //Print Column Names
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(reader.GetName(i) + "\t");
    }

    Console.Write("\n");

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

Test result
[image]
[image]